# Importing formulas with IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-sheets, formula, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I am using IMPORTRANGE to synchronise different sheets but the function only seems to import cell values and not any underlying formulas.

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding this is how it works. The formulas will calculate on the target sheet and return a value. ImportRange will then pull through these values. If you want to perform calculations over multiple import ranges you would need to have the formulas on the same sheet as your ImportRange formulas; not pull the formulas through to recalculate on the Main Sheet.

e.g (*very simplified example*):

[Main Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-3GZ4nk_PVMpidhzvNmQs-UQtO9n-b9yO3xGmUkrKRU/edit#gid=0)

[ImportSheet1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zM4G035sDbQo4fS9xcBnl2Nlw5gJw_evULfYEMCnna4/edit#gid=0)

ImportSheet2 (*can't post third link as I don't have enough Rep but it's the same as ImportSheet2 but with different figures*).